# How can I draw directly to screen?

Tags: java, rendering, screen

Is there a Graphics context that Java can utilize so that the programmer can draw directly to the screen rather than a window?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve pretty much what you describe (print arbitrary contents to an area of the screen of your choice) using SWT. The following snippet will display an empty rectangle (you can print arbitrary contents there e.g. using a Canvas).

```
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(SWT.NO_TRIM);
shell.setSize(50,50);
shell.setLocation(0,0); //show in upper left corner of main screen
//... add your custom contents
shell.open()
for(;!shell.isDisposed();)
  if(!display.readAndDispatch())
    display.sleep();
```

http://www.eclipse.org/swt/